# List selection with read and write permission

Tags: interaction-design, ux-designer

We have a list selection control, which has a special function to set read only or read write permissions while moving to "selected list" the current design is like in the below image.

[image]

To work with this user first press "R" or "RW" button and then moves available list items to the "Selected" list items. Default is "R".

Is there any better approach for this design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to remove the need of two clicks in order to dismiss an item and separate the concerns. Here are two solutions I could come with that are easier to work with in my opinion. For the second image the drag&drop is optional can work with two separate buttons. Hope it helps.

[image: same container if grouping is required]

[image: different containers for selected items]

Thanks for reply,

Both are good. I also created one solution which is below.

[image]

While you could use this you should be aware that you are adding one more click in the user interaction with the control, and that might slow him down. Coming from an enterprise environment I can tell you that every layer of action that can be removed, should be removed.

Comment: Items in list 2 should still have the "remove" possibility for consistency with your initial setup and you should know that this approach will, in a measure, influence the user to use the ReadOnly option.

Comment: I agree Aleodor Tabarcea.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove "R" and "RW" buttons. Place a combobox for each item in the selected list with values "R" and "RW". The default value of the combobox will be "R". Something like this :

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0AVms.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: This looks good, but imagine if there are 10 items user have to do this task 10 times.